# Detecting empty cursor before exiting stored procedure

Tags: oracle, exception, cursor

I have the following statement:

```
OPEN PARAM_RS FOR
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE my_NUMBER = param_number;
```

How can I "accurately" test PARAM_US, so that I can execute another statement if it's empty?  **I still need to return PARAM_US as an OUT parameter.**

I have tried

```
if (PARAM_RS%rowcount = 0) THEN...
```

But this test was positive even though there are rows in the result set.

I also try to use NO_DATA_FOUND exception, but it wasn't getting triggered.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to *fetch* from cursor in order to find whether there's something there or not. Have a look at the following example:

```
SQL> declare
  2    param_rs sys_refcursor;
  3    rec      emp%rowtype;
  4  begin
  5    open param_rs for
  6      select * from emp
  7      where deptno = &par_deptno;
  8    fetch param_rs into rec;
  9    if param_rs%notfound then
 10       dbms_output.put_line('Nothing has been found');
 11    else
 12       dbms_output.put_line('Oh yes, I found something!');
 13    end if;
 14  end;
 15  /
Enter value for par_deptno: 10
Oh yes, I found something!

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> /
Enter value for par_deptno: 87
Nothing has been found

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

**[EDIT]**

If you want to reuse it in order to get the whole data set, yes - you'll have to open it again. Otherwise, the first row (the one you fetched in order to check whether there's something in cursor or not) would be "lost".

Here's an example:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test (par_deptno in number, param_rs out sys_refcursor)
  2  is
  3    rec      emp%rowtype;
  4  begin
  5    open param_rs for
  6      select * from emp
  7      where deptno = par_deptno;
  8    fetch param_rs into rec;
  9    if param_rs%notfound then
 10       dbms_output.put_line('Nothing has been found');
 11    else
 12       dbms_output.put_line('Oh yes, I found something!');
 13       open param_rs for
 14         select * from emp
 15         where deptno = par_deptno;
 16    end if;
 17  end;
 18  /

Procedure created.

SQL> select ename from emp where deptno = 10;

ENAME
----------
CLARK
KING
MILLER

SQL> var l_out refcursor
SQL> exec p_test(10, :l_out);
Oh yes, I found something!

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print l_out

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE          SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         7839 09.06.1981       2450                    10
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT            17.11.1981       5000                    10
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           7782 23.01.1982       1300                    10

SQL>
```

Comment: @Littlefoot...thanks! but I forgot a very important detail...I need to be able to "return" PARAM_RS as an out parameter.  Fetching the record will make PARAM_RS unusable right?

Comment: Yes, Johnny. You'd have to open it once again. I edited my message, have a look at another example.

Comment: I accepted this answer because of its technicality.  :)

Answer (score 0):

`%ROWCOUNT` attribute of the cursor will be zeroed when it is opened, even if there are rows in the resultset. The attribute returns the number of rows fetched so far, so it will be zero before the first `FETCH`.

Similarly, the `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception won't be raised by an `OPEN`, that is thrown when a `FETCH` doesn't return a row.

---

To answer your question, I don't believe there is any test of an open cursor to determine if its "empty" , without attempting to fetch from it.

Answer (score 0):

A ref cursor is a pointer which to a chunk of memory: opening it simply associates the query to the memory space but doesn't execute it. It's not until we execute the fetch that we know whether the query will return anything. There's nothing strange about that, it's exactly how regular SQL queries work.

This is why neither testing for `sql%rowcount` or `no_data_found` will work: they are populated after a fetch. There is no way to "test" whether a cursor will return records without actually trying.

So, how to handle cursors which don't return any records? The normal behaviour is to allow the calling program to deal with it. This is the usual implementation. Usual because it's normally the calling program which has the most information about the current transaction, and therefore is best placed to know what to do.

That would look something like this [(full implementation on LiveSQL - free Oracle TechNet account required)](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/ghmf1tkhp1ad9tjy3n5lek5cz):

Given an API ...

```
create or replace package test1 as
    type cur1 is ref cursor return my_table%rowtype;

    procedure get_param (p_param in number, p_rs out cur1);
    procedure get_def_param (p_rs out cur1);
end;
/
```

... the calling program interacts with it like this:

```
declare
    rc test1.cur1;
    rec my_table%rowtype;
begin
    test1.get_param(42, rc);
    fetch rc into rec;
    if rc%notfound then
        close rc;
        test1.get_def_param(rc);
        fetch rc into rec;
    end if;
    dbms_output.put_line('result='||rec.description);
    close rc;
end;
/
```

However, if you really want the called program to handle the empty result set it can be done. The trick is to open a test cursor inside the called program, get the default record if that doesn't fetch anything and then open the parameter ref cursor with a guaranteed result set.

```
create or replace package test1 as
    type cur1 is ref cursor return my_table%rowtype;
    type nt is table of my_table%rowtype;

    procedure get_param (p_param in number, p_rs out cur1);
end;
/
create or replace package body test1 as


    procedure get_param (p_param in number, p_rs out cur1) is
        rc cur1;
        recs nt;
    begin
        open rc for
             select t.* 
             from my_table t
             where t.my_number = p_param;
        fetch rc bulk collect into recs;
        if recs.count() = 0 then
            close rc;
            open rc for
                select t.* 
                from my_table t
                where t.my_number = 1;
            fetch rc bulk collect into recs;
        end if;
        close rc;
        open p_rs for 
             select * from table(recs);
    end  get_param;

end;
/
```

Now the calling program is much simpler:

```
declare
    rc test1.cur1;
    rec my_table%rowtype;
begin
    test1.get_param(42, rc);
    fetch rc into rec;
    dbms_output.put_line('result='||rec.description);
    close rc;
end;
/
```